# MySQL : How to break down large data table(nearly 80 Billion rows) into multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have a single large table in MySQL that has over 80 Billion records. Querying in that table takes a long period of time, even simple count(*) doesn't execute.

I tried loading data into multiple tables with a proc and even then a single day's data load takes more than 3 hours to complete.

Can anyone help me with an alternative solution to break down the data in my single large table into multiple tables? Is my way of using a proc to load data into multiples tables the only alternative?

Thanks and Regards,
Success

Comment: Have you tried indexing?

Comment: Partitioning, perhaps?

Comment: try using an index first and only query index

Comment: 80 million records is not that big a table. If you say  that even a simple `count(*)` doesn't run, then you have a serious problem. With your hardware or your OS maybe.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I'm sorry I meant 80 billion, a typo. Edited original question.

Comment: @johnSmith I do have indexing

Comment: Yep, see partitioning